# Using element.find() by class in Angular Unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jqlite

When running this test, I keep getting the error `Expected undefined to be true.`

```
it('should have the right classes', function() {
   // this doesnt work
   expect(element.find('.exampleClass').hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(true);

   // but this works
   expect(element.find('span').hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(true);
});
```

How can I use jqlite to find an element by `id` and `class`?

Comment: You can't. jqLite doesn't support selectors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is because angular-jqlite (very lightweight library when compared to jquery itself) `find` is limited to look up by tag names only. You can use `element.querySelector(All)` and wrap it in `angular.element`. i.e

```
  var elm = element[0];
  expect(angular.element(elm.querySelector('.exampleClass')).hasClass('ng-hide')).toBe(true);

  //Or even
  expect(elm.querySelector('.exampleClass.ng-hide')).toBeDefined();
```

[See documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite)

> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name